# Borrowing within a vector of structures

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a vector of structures and i would like to update one structure with values in another. For my use case, I prefer to do it in a loop. I'm hitting the borrow-checker but it seems like there must be a simple solution to this type of problem.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Column {
    header: String,
    amount: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut spreadsheet: Vec<Column> = Vec::new();

    spreadsheet.push(Column {
        header: "Car".to_string(),
        amount: 30300,
    });
    spreadsheet.push(Column {
        header: "House".to_string(),
        amount: 210800,
    });
    spreadsheet.push(Column {
        header: "Total".to_string(),
        amount: 0,
    });

    for column in &mut spreadsheet {
        //mutable borrow here
        if column.header == "Total" {
            column.amount = spreadsheet[0].amount //immutable borrow here
                        + spreadsheet[1].amount;
        } else {
            column.amount -= 300;
        }
    }

    for column in spreadsheet {
        println!("{:?}", column);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, not what you expect, but this would work https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d953f6e706cf72f64983fe93cd3a192b

Comment: Thank you hellow - nice suggestion - i may very well need to use two loops/iterations - i was hoping that i could do it in one -

Comment: You can easily do it in one iteration if you just defer pushing the `Total` until after you've processed the other items; or, with slightly more thought, by saving its index / reference and doing the mutation after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set spreadsheet vector element while iterating inside of it. Since you always wanting to use `spreadsheet[0].amount` and  `spreadsheet[1].amount` you can clone this values into another variable and work with them instead of using them inside of spreadsheet.

Here is the working code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Column {
    header: String,
    amount: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut spreadsheet: Vec<Column> = Vec::new();

    spreadsheet.push(Column {
        header: "Car".to_string(),
        amount: 30300,
    });
    spreadsheet.push(Column {
        header: "House".to_string(),
        amount: 210800,
    });
    spreadsheet.push(Column {
        header: "Total".to_string(),
        amount: 0,
    });

    let car_amount = spreadsheet[0].amount;
    let header_amount = spreadsheet[1].amount;

    spreadsheet.iter_mut().for_each(|column| {
        if column.header == "Total" {
            column.amount = car_amount + header_amount;
        } else {
            column.amount -= 300;
        }
    });

    for column in spreadsheet {
        println!("{:?}", column);
    }
}
```

[Playground with using `iter()`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e96f8297f525d4359d78722cdb474bec)

Since you want to do these operations in a for loop instead of iterator you can change the `spreadsheet.iter_mut()...` code block to the following:

```
for column in &mut spreadsheet {
    if column.header == "Total" {
        column.amount = car_amount + header_amount;
    } else {
        column.amount -= 300;
    }
}
```

[Playground with using `for loop`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=567693edcdae2f07dfec1de2f3650477)

Comment: @trentcl, oh yeah i missed that. Thanks.. Fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Thank you Akiner - my 'real' problem is very much more complex and pulling the values out beforehand is less attractive.  I was hoping there was some 'trick'  i could use -